# Consequence of completeness axiom proof

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Prove that , for a set $A⊂R$, $s=sup⁡A$ if and only if

i)  $a≤s$ for all $a∈A$.

ii) For any $ε>0$, there exists $a∈A$ such that $a>s-ε$

I can easily prove that if $s=sup⁡A$ then $a≤s$ for all $a∈A$ using the definition of sup, but for part ii), I'm still struggling. I also have hard time trying to prove the converse too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $\sup(A)$ is defined as the unique number $s$ satisfying the following properties :

1. $s$ is an upper bound for $A$
2. If $t$ is any other upper bound for $A$, then $s \leq t$

Given that, let's prove (ii) : Let $s =\sup(A)$ and let $\epsilon > 0$. Suppose that there is no $a \in A$ such that $a > s-\epsilon$. Then that would imply that
$$
a \leq s-\epsilon \quad\forall a\in A
$$
Hence, $s-\epsilon$ would be an upper bound for $A$. By condition (2) above, this would imply
$$
s\leq s-\epsilon
$$
which is absurd because $\epsilon > 0$. Hence, there must exist an $a\in A$ such that $a>s-\epsilon$

Added: To prove the converse. Assume (1) and (2), then by (1), $s$ is an upper bound. Now, if $t$ is any other upper bound for $A$, then we want to show that $s\leq t$ :

Choose $\epsilon > 0$, then by assumption, there is $a\in A$ such that
$$
a > s-\epsilon
$$
Since $a\leq t$, it follows that
$$
s-\epsilon < t \qquad\forall \epsilon > 0
$$
This is true for every $\epsilon > 0$, therefore $s\leq t$

Comment: I understand this part, how do you prove the converse of this statement. I understand that i) guarantee that $s$ is the upper bound of $A$. I want to show that $s$ is the least upper bound of $A$ to conclude $s=sup A$, but I don't know how to use ii) to show that.

Comment: What do you mean by "...let $\epsilon \to 0$"?

Comment: @Pedro Shorthand for what I edited to.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan (I know, just think it might be misleading for people that don't.)